# how can I upload a file(excel) to a specific location on my C drive using knockout and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, knockout.js

I am writing an application in knockout and asp.net where I am trying to upload an excel file. I have written code to upload the file but I need to know how to upload to a specific location for example any location on the C drive. This is the code I have written so far. I think what I am missing is the part where I need to put the path to save to but I am not sure where to put it

```
<div class="control-group" data-bind="fileDrag: multiFileData">
                                                   @*<div class="form-group row">*@
                                                      <div>
                                                         @*<div class="col-md-6">*@
                                                         <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <!-- ko foreach: {data: multiFileData().dataURLArray, as: 'dataURL'} -->
                                                            <img style="height: 100px; @*margin: 5px;*@" class="img-rounded  thumb" data-bind="attr: { src: dataURL }, visible: dataURL">
                                                            <!-- /ko -->
                                                            <div data-bind="ifnot: fileData().dataURL">
                                                               <label class="drag-label">Drag files here</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                         </div>
                                                         <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <input type="file" multiple data-bind="fileInput: multiFileData, customFileInput: {
                                                      buttonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                                                      fileNameClass: 'disabled form-control',
                                                      onClear: onClear,
                                                       }" accept="excel/*">
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                </div>
```

Comment: Reconsider your requirements. A web browser can't save or read files in arbitrary locations; the user must choose a location by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set any folder where you want to upload files in ASP.NET, you should add that folder in IIS, when configuring your ASP.NET application. So, when you set your application in IIS:

1. Open IIS
2. Expand Sites->[Your website/application]
3. Right click on [Your website/application]
4. Choose Add Virtual Directory
5. Set Alias and Physical path

You will use this Alias in your ASP.NET application as folder location, and it will know into what physical location on server to put files.
Hope this helped.
Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your comment but what I actually am looking for is a way to upload using knockout on client side then upload on the server using C# MVC